# Is my laptop charger is working as harmonic filter and absorbing harmonics?

Tags: inverter, ups, passive-filter, harmonics, power-filtering

I have a square wave backup inverter (UPS). Whenever the power goes out, UPS turns on but all the fans run with noise and humming sound. I know it is because of square wave and harmonics. But when I plug in my laptop charger during power outs into socket (connected to UPS output), the noise is gone. What is going on here? Is my laptop charger is working as harmonic filter and absorbing harmonics? Same thing happens when energy saver is turned on but the effect is little.

Comment: May I suggest going over your question again? Parts of it make little sense: "load is supplied power by it"? "it is because of square wave and harmonics"? 

What could be going on is that the DC to AC converter inside the UPS has a minimum load requirement top operate with a clean output.

Comment: I have edited the question, more explanation: ”load is supplied” means lights and fans are connected to output of UPS. When AC machine is given a square wave instead of pure sine wave it cause noise, vibration and heat. And I could not understand the last part about minimum load requirement. Can you elaborate it a little more

Comment: Do not supply a device that is meant to run on 50 Hz sinusoidal voltage with a square wave. This can cause significant damage and excessive heating in capacitors and transformers and motors, in adition to causing a lot of vibration and wear on motors. The cause of this is the high-frequency components in a square wave, which will cause high currents to flow through capacitors, and cause higher losses in transformers. Also, please edit the original question instead of just elaborating in the comments, this way it is more clear for people new to the question.

Comment: thanks but that still doesn't answer my question. ”what is the role of ”laptop charger" and "energy saver" in reducing noise. PS: I know the damages done by of square wave ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All switched-mode power supplies have filter capacitors on the input.  These are mainly to stop electromagnetic interference escaping from the power supply, but they will also reduce any voltage spikes and harmonics coming in.

It may be that the filters on your laptop power supply are just enough to round off the edges of the square wave from the UPS.  They may be working hard to do this, and they may fail eventually.